# Use a particular drive if path exists in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that sometimes people run and since batch files don't allow UNC mapping, they need specific drive mappings.

The problem is that some people who run this file will have the server mapped to different letters, specifically M or P.

So what I want to do is make a variable to score the drive so I can concatenate it into other path commands where possible because sometimes they will have:

```
M:\Path\to\stuff\on\server
```

or

```
P:\Path\to\stuff\on\server
```

So what I want to do is say if `M:\Path\to\stuff\on\server`" exists then use drive `M`, if `"P:\Path\to\stuff\on\server"` exists then use drive `P`.

Is there a way to do this in batch script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you specifically only have `M:` and `P:` in this example:

```
@for %%i in (m: p:) do @if exist %%i cd /d %%i
echo %cd%
```

It can be extended to more drives. Additionally please note that if the user has both `M:\` and `P:\` drives, it will `cd` to both and end up in the last one in the list. Therefore using a known directory is a better solution on the mapping.

```
@for %%i in (m: p:) do @if exist "%%i\Path\to\stuff\on\server" cd /d "%%I\Path\to\stuff\on\server"
echo %cd%
```

if you want to set it as a variable to use it anywhere else in the script, then simply assign the drive letter to a variable like so:

```
@for %%i in (m: p:) do @if exist %%i set "mydrive=%%i\"
echo %mydrive%
```

Alternatively, without needing to use variables, you can use the already assigned metavariable `%%i` to use the drive letter as you please:

```
@for %%i in (m: p:) do @if exist %%i (
    echo my drive letter is %%i
    dir %%i
    cd /d %%i
 )
```

Comment: So after that for loop and if statement, if I want to start doing things like writing to text files on specific paths on that drive, do I need to explicitly reference the drive or will it work with relative references?

Comment: no need to reference the drive. You are already on it seeing as we `cd /d` so by doing something like `echo Hello world>test.txt` would create that file in the path we `cd`d to. I will update the answer to show you how to use it as a variable should you need to use it for other items.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could utilise is to create a temporary mapping using pushD.

```
pushd \\Server\Share\path
```

When you are done with that temporary mapping just use **popd** to destroy it.

Where \Server\Share\path is the network resource to which you want to map a drive letter.

As soon as you use it, the PushD command will instantly map a drive letter to the network resource and then change to that drive right in the Command Prompt window.

Keep in mind that the PushD command allocates drive letters from Z: on down and will use the first unused drive letter that it finds.

Comment: What is a sample usage of pushd, using the drive, and then popd? What happens if I don't popd correctly?

Comment: Taking your example, the command could be pushd "\\Path\to\stuff\on\server", popd essentially just returns that drive letter back to pool, so if you forgot to popd then that drive letter won't be returned back. Here is a guide on how to use push and popd - https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-the-pushd-popd-commands-for-quick-network-drive-mapping-in-windows-7/

Comment: My concern is too much risk in case I mess something up, I don't want to be remapping drives